# dynamically render a unique button on a react component that is being used several times on a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize, jsx

I'm new to react and have to make a project for my bootcamp with it and I am having trouble getting every movie component I render to have an individual button. Every time I click one button, the rest of the buttons on the page act like they are also clicked. Here is my movie component that is being called on.
Heres my first row of components and the buttons are the green ones on the bottom left corner. https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T571CRHGE-F826BKX7S/api.png.

```
importReact, { Component} from"react";
importAPIfrom"../utils/API"
classMovieextendsComponent{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={

        color:'green',
        icon:'add',
        result:[]
     };
}

componentDidMount() {
     this.topMovies();
}

topMovies=() =>{
    API.topMovies()
    .then(res=>this.setState({ result:res.data.results}))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}

handleClick=event=>{
     if(this.state.color==='green'){
         this.setState({color:'red'});
     } else{
         this.setState({color:'green'});
     }

     if(this.state.icon==='add') {
          this.setState({icon:'remove'});
     } else{
          this.setState({icon:'add'});
     }
}

render() {
     constimgURL="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/"

     return(
         <div>
              {
                  this.state.result.map((movieList) =>(

                  <div className="col s4 movieBox">
                      <div className="card">
                          <div className="card-image">
                               <img src={imgURL +movieList.poster_path} />
                               <span className="card-title"><a id={this.state.color} onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light"><i className="material-icons">{this.state.icon}</i></a></span>
                          </div>
                          <div className="card-content movieInfo">
                               <p>Title:{movieList.title}</p>
                               <p>Genre:{movieList.genre_ids}</p>
                               <p>Rating:{movieList.vote_average}</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
                 ))
             }

        </div>
    )
}
}
exportdefaultMovie;
```

Comment: The link to screenshot is not visible

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `handleClick` function ( in fact all functions ) inside the constructor:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={

        color:'green',
        icon:'add',
        result:[]
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onClick={()=> this.handleClick()} will also work.

Answer (score 0):

.map() calls a provided callback for each element in your array. So this means that you are creating several buttons that will execute the same event on each of your elements. I suggest creating a row component that handles your onClickEvent and then you could pass the component an id or use an in line arrow function () => this.handleClick(). (this does create a anonymous function on each click and could potentially be bad for performance in larger apps but could work in your case if you don't want to create a row component)

Also you should read up on why using keys with unique ids is important.
https://coderwall.com/p/jdybeq/the-importance-of-component-keys-in-react-js

Hope that helps.